# cufon not rendering the fonts correctly

Tags: php, html, cufon

I am designing a website using the psd provided. I am using same fonts(lanenar font) in psd and in website(convert using cufon tool) but the website fonts is very thin as compared to the font in psd.(Cufon is successfully applied but result is not same)
The size of font is same and even I am using the font-style bold. so I needs to know the problem so that I can solve it.

here is my webdesign :http://designs.digitaldreamstech.com/motto/index.php/pages/details?albumId=1

image is http://designs.digitaldreamstech.com/motto/images/Gallery.jpg

Please check menu only as I have applied cufon in menu part only.

Here is what I have done

1) convert the font using cufon convertor tool
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

2) applied using cufon-yu.js and the font js file generated

do you think it the problem related to conversion.? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please provide more information. browser etc, system you are working on (mac/ubuntu antialias fonts in browser) etc...

By the way, Photoshop and Webfonts are not exactly compareable. Even if they are using the same .ttf

Comment: I have checked in all browser (chrome,firefox,IE) and I have checked the psd design on window 7 and xp(both are same).                   Yes, I know Photoshop and Webfonts are not exactly compareable but they are mostly similar in many cases.

Comment: this might not be the answer to your question, but it will maybe help solving your problem: just change the font replacement method ! i was working with these tools too long before font-face became popular and never used cufon, simply because there are better alternatives: check http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/typography-articles/a-web-designers-guide-to-font-replacement-methods/